# Remove log4j v1 dependency on the existing services in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, log4j

We were using log4j V1 and now upgraded to log4j V2 on hadoop clusters and services. How to remove the dependency of log4j V1?

Answer (score 1):

Run `hadoop classpath`, and look at all the paths. Find where `log4j-1.2.jar` might exist, and remove them.

Note: I don't think you can simply just "swap" Log4j 1.x with 2.x and expect everything to continue working. There should be open JIRA's across various Hadoop-related projects for properly upgrading to Log4j2.